# How to truncate table when foreign dependencies exist via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

For testing purposes I have a method that takes in a `SqlConnection` or a connection string and a string. The method examines the `SqlConnection` or the `DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` against a set of 'dangerous' strings, if the connection string has any 'dangerous' strings, it doesn't execute its query.

I basically need to know how to execute (via C#) a truncate/delete all data in table HOWEVER the problem is foreign dependencies. I am trying the following method. Remove all dependencies, delete the table and then reinstate all dependencies however I am having an issue with my reinstate all dependencies code. How can I do this via C#?

Main method that should delete the table.

```
public int DeleteFromDatabase(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string tableName)
{
        int success = 0;

        string sqlTrunc = "Delete from " + tableName;

        if (isSafeSqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            DropAllConstraints();

            using (sqlConnection)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlTrunc, sqlConnection);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }

            ReinstateAllConstraints(); //<=error happens here.
        }
        return success;
}
```

This drops all constraints:

```
public void DropAllConstraints()
{
    string[] queries = File.ReadAllLines(@"Utility\UnsafeStrings\dropallcontraint.txt");

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var item in queries)
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand(item, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This checks that the connection passed in isn't a live server:

```
private bool isSafeSqlConnection(SqlConnection connection)
{
    string pathToUNsafeStrings = @"Utility\UnsafeStrings\UnsafeStrings.txt";
    string[] unsafeStrings = File.ReadAllLines(pathToUNsafeStrings);

    foreach (var item in unsafeStrings)
    {
        if (connection.ConnectionString.Contains(item))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This method essentially executes every entry returned from this query:

```
select
    'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + object_name(fk.parent_object_id) + 
    ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + fk.name +
    ' FOREIGN KEY(' + c1.name + ') REFERENCES dbo.' + 
    object_name(fk.referenced_object_id) + '(' + c2.name + ')' as col1
from 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
inner join
    sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id and c1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
inner join
    sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id and c2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id

public void ReinstateAllConstraints()
{
    string[] reinstateAllConstraints = File.ReadAllLines(@"Utility\UnsafeStrings\reisntateconstraint.txt");

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var item in reinstateAllConstraints)
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand(item, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You either delete the dependencies or you don't truncate records that are referenced elsewhere.  Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @Will How can i ensure all the dependencies are reinstated once ive deleted the dependencies?

Comment: If record X depends on record Y, you can only ever delete X and Y or leave them alone. You can't delete Y and leave X.

Comment: @Will Then how can I delete both via C#?

Comment: You either need to remove the dependencies (not my recommendation) or remove the children rows first, then delete the parent rows. You could also change your relationships to cascade on delete.

Comment: Why dont you use cascade delete?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro as in alter my tables with the 'on delete cascade'?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this workflow:

1. Disable the foreign key check.
2. Delete all registers from tables that references the table that you want delete.
3. Delete all registers from table that you want delete.
4. Enable foreign key check.

You can see in this code below(**I am using C# 6**)

```
public bool TruncateTable(string tableName)
{
    string sqlTrunc = $"Delete from {tableName}";

    if (isSafeSqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        DisableAllForeignKeys();

        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            DeleteAllDependencies(tableName, sqlConnection);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlTrunc, sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        EnableAllForeignKeys();
    }
    return success;
}


public void DisableAllForeignKeys(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand($"EXEC sp_msforeachtable \"ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all\"", sqlConnection))
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public void EnableAllForeignKeys(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand($"EXEC sp_msforeachtable \"ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all\"", sqlConnection))
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

private static void DeleteAllDependencies(string tableName, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    var sql =
        $@"SELECT t.name  AS 'Table that contains FK', 
fk.name AS 'FK Name',
t1.Name AS 'Table that is being referenced'
FROM   sys.foreign_key_columns fkc 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t1 ON t1.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1 ON c1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id AND c1.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON t.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  (sc.name + '.' +t1.name) = 'dbo.{
            tableName}';";

    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sql;

    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> tuples;
    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var enumerator = dataReader.GetEnumerator();
        tuples = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
                           .TakeWhile(i => enumerator.MoveNext())
                           .Select(i => (IDataRecord)enumerator.Current)
                           .Select(dr => Tuple.Create(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1), dr.GetString(2)))
                           .ToList();
    }


    foreach (var tuple in tuples)
    {
        using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM {tuple.Item1}";
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: like my other code, the disabling of all foreign constraints is working, its when enabling all foreign keys thats thowing a SqlException The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BookingRevisionAddOnProductSelections_BookingRevisionId". The conflict occurred in database "Dev.DbContext", table "dbo.BookingRevisions", column 'Id'.

Comment: @DonnieBrasco I just changed my code to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want to configure the relations to propagate changes accordingly ("cascade"), so that when one part of the relation is deleted, the other gets deleted or updated as well.

The DBMS is right in saying that you can not activate a fk relation if the items you are referring to from the other table are missing.